# Java Game - Key Pressed

Tags: java, key, awt, keyevent, pressed

I'm doing an Orthogonal Tiled Map Java game, when my Ship moves to the x and y bounds pressing a direction Key it stops moving(as intended), but if i keep pushing the Key my character gets out of the Screen.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            ship = world.getShip();

            switch(keycode){
                    case Keys.W:
                        if (ship.getPosition().y<28.5f){

                            ship.getVelocity().y = 1;}
                            else {
                                ship.getVelocity().y = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                    case Keys.S:
                        if (ship.getPosition().y1){
                            ship.getVelocity().y = -1;}
                        else {
                            ship.getVelocity().y = 0;
                    }
                            break;
                    case Keys.A:
                            if (ship.getPosition().x0)
                            ship.getVelocity().x = -1.5f;
                            else{
                                ship.getVelocity().x = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                    case Keys.D:
                            if (ship.getPosition().x<39){

                           ship.getVelocity().x = 1;
                            }
                            else{
                                ship.getVelocity().x = 0;
                            }
                            break;
    default:
                            break;
            }
            return true;
    }

   @Override
   public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
           ship = world.getShip();
            switch(keycode){
                    case Keys.W:
                            if(ship.getVelocity().y == 1)
                                    ship.getVelocity().y = 0;
                            break;
                    case Keys.S:
                            if(ship.getVelocity().y == -1)
                                    ship.getVelocity().y = 0;
                            break;
                    case Keys.A:
                            if(ship.getVelocity().x == -1.5f)
                                    ship.getVelocity().x = 0;
                            break;
                    case Keys.D:
                            if(ship.getVelocity().x == 1)
                                    ship.getVelocity().x = 0;
                            break;

                    default:
                            break;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

What should i do to keep my Ship on Screen if a key is keeping pushed?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should i do to keep my Ship on Screen if a key is keeping pushed?

Start by using current API's. `keyUp()` and `keyDown()` have been deprecated since JDK1.1

Start by reading [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for some more current ideas on how to handle something like this. The code examples do basic bounds checking to make sure you can't move the component off the screen.